# Partially dynamic mapping

Tags: elasticsearch

In my index "process" I have a type "logs". For this type, I have this mapping:

```
{
    "process": {
        "mappings": {
            "logs": {
                "properties": {
                    "channel": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "context": {
                        "type": "object"
                    },
                    "datetime": {
                        "type": "date",
                        "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                    },
                    "extra": {
                        "type": "object"
                    "level": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "level_name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "message": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is, the "context" property and the "extra" property are dynamic fields, each document can have a different number of extra & context sub elements with different names.
When I set this mapping, and then I check `http://localhost:9200/process/_mapping/logs`, I see this very mapping. So it's worked. Also the answer of the setting is `{acknowledge: true}` . So far so good.

Then, I add a several documents, or at least I try. The first document changes ES mapping!

The new mapping is:

```
{
  "process" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "logs" : {
        "properties" : {
          "channel" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "context" : {
            "properties" : {
              "columns" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "count" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "errorMessage" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "serviice" : {
                "type" : "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "datetime" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
          },
          "extra" : {
            "properties" : {
              "uid" : {
                "type" : "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "level" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "level_name" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "message" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And when I try to add a new document, it doesn't match this new mapping and trigger this error :

```
MapperParsingException[object mapping [context] trying to serialize a value with no field associated with it, current value [pid]]
```

So I am clearly missing something.

1. Why my mapping get overwritten ? I tried to remove the entire index and to build everything up from scratch, same behavior.
2. Is what I want to achieve possible ? or do I have the wrong approach ?

EDIT : the document that is inserted and seems to update the mapping :

```
{
  "message": "Starting background process `{service}`, registered under the ID ",
  "context": {
    "id": null,
    "serviice": "fiduceo.import"
  },
  "level": 250,
  "level_name": "NOTICE",
  "channel": "process",
  "datetime": "2016-06-09T11:23:42.304859+02:00",
  "extra": {
    "uid": "d1cb925"
  }
}
```

And the one who fails:

```
{
  "message": "Background process created (pid: {pid})",
  "context": [
    "pid",
    18871
  ],
  "level": 250,
  "level_name": "NOTICE",
  "channel": "process",
  "datetime": "2016-06-09T11:23:41.519456+02:00",
  "extra": {
    "uid": "09fe183"
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. I wouldn't say your mapping gets overwritten, but updated. That means all defined fields stay like they are, and missing fields (that are not in the mapping but in the document) are added.

2. What you want to achieve is possible in general, but you have some conflict with your mapping of fields and the JSON input. Please provide your JSON document that failes for this very mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your context field contains an invalid JSON

**it should look like this:**

```
"context": {
    "pid": 18871
  },
```

compared to your version:

```
"context": [
    "pid",
    18871
  ]
```

---

EDIT: In order to give a full answer (and repeat what was written in the comment):

1. Your mapping is not overwritten, but updated. This happens for the fields that are contained in the new indexed JSON document but not the initial mapping.
2. It's possible. And your general approach is correct.

Comment: I have noticed that and already fixed it. I didn't show the corrected version since the underlying problem remains. Why can't I add a keyless (implicitly numericly indexed) sub-element ? This maybe also means that a context.foo element must always contains the same structure of data ?

Comment: is it still the exact same error message you get? 

You are allowed to omit values from the mapping in new documents, but you are not allowed to store one time a number and afterwards a string into the same field.

Comment: check the updated answer with regards to the parantheses of the "correct" version. The first time you store an array with [] and the second time its an object using {}

Comment: After the fix I no longer have the error. Thx for all these information.